# Wordpress Actions to Extend Plugin

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

I newby here ... Woocommerce Wishlist plugin so that I can have the "add to wishlist" on my products page and not just the single page.

I added this to my functions file but it creates errors. I have done a ton of searching, but unable to find a solution.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

**Code:** `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array( WC_Wishlists_Plugin, 'add_to_wishlist_button' ), 10 );`

**Error:** Warning: Use of undefined constant WC_Wishlists_Plugin - assumed 'WC_Wishlists_Plugin' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably your code is deprecated.

Try the bellow code and check if it would achieve the result that you wants.

It worked out for me but the design wasn't good enough

```php
function addWishlistButton() {
        global $wishlists;
        
        ?>
        <form class="cart wishlist-cart-form" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'
              action="<?php echo add_query_arg( array( 'add-to-wishlist-itemid' => get_the_ID() )); ?>">


            
            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_ID() ); ?>" />
            <?php $wishlists->add_to_wishlist_button(); ?>
            </form>
        <?php
    }
    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'addWishlistButton', 10 );
```

**PS: ** You need to add the code inside your functions.php

Comment: Hey Gaby, thank you for that ... you have saved the day. You were 100% correct that the code I was using was depreciated. The snippet you gave worked excellent! Thanks again. =)